# Laravel Keep Data in class

Tags: php, laravel

I want to do something like this.

```php
namespace App\Repositories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class SomeRepository {
    /**
     * HasMany
     */
    private $relation;

    public function __construct(HasMany $hasMany) {
        $this->relation = $hasMany;
    }

    public function setStatus($obj_id, $status) {
        $status_on = $this->getStatusOn();

        switch($status) {
            case 0:
                $status_on->status = 0;
                $status_on->save();
                break;
            case 1:
                $status_to_on = $this->relation->where('id', '=', $obj_id)->first();
                if ($status_on) {
                    $status_on->status = 0;
                    $status_on->save();
                }
                $status_to_on->status = 1;
                $status_to_on->save();
                break;
        }
    }

    public function getStatusOn() {
        return $this->relation->where('status', '=', 1)->orderBy('order', 'ASC')->first();
    }
}
```

When After I use `get()` to get all the relation, it can't get any data by `$this->relation->where('status', '=', 1);`.

I'm thinking, should I use newQuery?

My problem is how to get the data from MySQL and keep it in `SomeRepository` and grab data when I want (because I need to be able to filter any data from `hasMany` at any time).

Is some logic wrong in my design? or how to design the class I want in Laravel?
Many thanks, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Have you tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50628649/2836233)?

Comment: I'm really thanks your help, I'm using the other easy way to get my target. I save model on constructor instead of relation to get the data I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HasMany` object cannot be used to achieve what you want because the object cannot be reused in the way you want. 
Executing the underlying query using `get()` or `first()` in the object doesn't reset it to its previous state as passed in the constructor as you are expecting.

Example

```
function getBooks($model){
    $result = $model->get();
}

$model = new Book;
$books = getBooks($model);  //Gets books
$model = $model->where('published', true);
$books = getBooks($model);  //Gets only published books. Notice the where('published', true); condition called above on the model is still active?
```

You're no longer getting results when you reuse `relation` because the old queries and conditions executed on it are still active.
To maintain the state of the object passed in the constructor, you might have to make copies of it each time you want to use it.

```
namespace App\Repositories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class SomeRepository {
/**
 * HasMany
 */
private $relation;

public function __construct(HasMany $hasMany) {
    $this->relation = $hasMany;
}

private function copyRelation(){
  $clone = clone $this->relation;
  return $clone;
}

public function setStatus($obj_id, $status) {
    $status_on = $this->getStatusOn();

    switch($status) {
        case 0:
            $status_on->status = 0;
            $status_on->save();
            break;
        case 1:
            $status_to_on = $this->copyRelation()->where('id', '=', $obj_id)->first();
            if ($status_on) {
                $status_on->status = 0;
                $status_on->save();
            }
            $status_to_on->status = 1;
            $status_to_on->save();
            break;
    }
}

public function getStatusOn() {
    return $this->copyRelation()->where('status', '=', 1)->orderBy('order', 'ASC')->first();
}
```

Notice how I used `SomeRepository::copyRelation();`?

Note: The codes were not tested, I'm hoping you get the idea.